Is ln|x| + C really the most general antiderivative of 1/x?
I recently stumbled across a claim that $\ln |x| + C$ isn't the most general antiderivative of $1/x$. The argument was that the parts of the curve $\ln |x|$ separated by the $y$-axis do not have to be shifted by the same constant $C$. Therefore, an even more general antiderivative would be:
$ \displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}
x =\begin{cases} 
      \ln x+D & x\gt 0 \\
      \ln(-x) + C & x \lt0 \\
\end{cases}
$
Where $D, C \in\mathbb{R}$ are real constants which may or may not be the same.
I am wondering why we typically say that the antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\ln |x| + C$, when there seems to be an even more general function. Does it make any practical difference to even make a distinction between these functions?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2720780/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4466926/42969

The $+C$ in an indefinite integral is a locally constant function, so strictly speaking it has an invisible $(x)$. It matters here because the domain of $\frac1x$ is in two pieces.
